# Can a resident of Netherlands sponsor a French Schengen visa application?

Tags: visas, schengen, proof-provenance-of-funds, visa-sponsors

My girlfriend (Thailand) is planning to come to Europe for a short holiday. She is a student. I myself live in the Netherlands and have sufficient funds to be her sponsor in all expenses. The main destination/time spent of our trip will be in France, so we have to apply for the visa there. Except on the application they keep asking about the **France resident** that will act as sponsor. And it got me really confused whether I can still be her sponsor from abroad (even though I am still in a Schengen country). I would contact them myself but unfortunately it is Sunday. Anyone with the same experience?

Would another solution be to send her sufficient funds for her own bank statements? I can imagine they will want to see a stable income over the past few statements rather than 1 big amount right before the application.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to invite her to the Netherlands first, with you as a sponsor and just take a train/plane to France?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, that would mean lying about the main destination of the trip, which is a bad idea. Unless you can argue that the Netherlands **is** the main reason for the trip, regardless of length of stay.

Comment: That is in fact what we will do but since the majority of our stay is in France we have to apply for the visa there. Other than that the french process is way faster(appointment within 1 week, and about 3-10 working days after applying) than the dutch one (up to 3-4weeks waiting time for appointment alone, we did try to look into this already)

Comment: Sending her one-off funds to make her bank account look better is unwise, just as you surmised. See "funds parking" on this site.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, the sponsor letter allows you to invite someone to the country where you are a resident nothing else.

You could invite her to The Netherlands and get a Schengen Visa however please be aware of the below.

Even though the Schengen Visa would allow her to travel to France since that is the main destination of her trip you would be violating the regulations and risk a refusal by applying for the visa sponsored by the Netherlands

The relevant information about when an invite needs to come from the destination country and not is specified at the website below, in general it has to do with who will financially guarantee the trip.

[schengen Visa information](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/frequently-asked-questions-schengen-visa/)